# Axios: how to send large number of requests as fast as possible

Tags: node.js, nginx, axios, get, pm2

for a node project, I am getting some data at path /api, and I need to forward that data to some other api(not hosted on the same local host)
but the problem is, I am getting large amounts on request that I need to forward, example:
I am getting 100 requests, of which 50 are forwarded, remaining are pending
then 1000 in, 300 out
and this gap keeps increasing
eventually, most requests time out
any help?

I tried using other alternatives except axios
I also tried tweaking axios setting by using timeout and keepalive,etc
none of them gave proper results
ideally, I want data to travel as quickly as it possibly can, as I am recieveing 100req/s
and so I need to get the response at the same rate

I am using node js with nginx and pm2 if that helps